# Changing to a different WiFi connection

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I'm using MacBook Air running MacOS Sierra and using an IP address(provided by my college) that has been bound to my device's MAC address `manually`.

ie- My device's MAC address is has been bonded with a specific IP address provided by the College's network administrators.

So, I've manually configured the network connection with that specific IP address.

[image: Here is the configuration]

Now, when I connect to my phone's wi-fi (Redmi 4A), it gets connected (`DHCP`), the internet works well and after 2-3 minutes the internet finally disconnects even though I'm still connected to my phone's wi-fi.

Is this due to the manual network settings set only for the IP address provided by the college.

**EDIT:** :

I found that the manual setting for the college wifi is causing a problem. When connecting to phone's wifi, the `Using DHCP` option doesn't get automatically selected.

So, what I did is that when connecting to my phone's wifi, I selected the `Using DHCP` and it worked well.

But the problem now is that when I reconnect to my college wifi, the `Configure IPv4` now shows `Using DHCP` which I had previously selected when connecting to my phone's wifi.
Hence, when connecting to the college wifi, all the manual settings have disappeared and I have to fill the configuration details again.

Please suggest some workaround to deal with the above problem. I don't want to reconfigure all the `manual` settings again and again when I switch between the 2 wifis.

Comment: What are your TCP/IP settings for your Wi-Fi card? DNS, proxy, DHCP etc?

Comment: Didn't get you. But, I think I've put up the image with all the configured settings.

Comment: Try configuring IPv4 automatically using DHCP. Is there a reason you need to configure it manually? Are there any IPs listed in the DNS tab?

Comment: @TimD It works well when I select DHCP instead of manual mode(when connecting to phone) but all the configured manual settings get disappeared and when I've to reconnect to the college wifi then I have to manually configure it again.

Comment: @TimD Hope that the edit helps now narrow down the solution to deal with the problem.

Comment: You can setup different settings for home and at work/college using network locations. See [How to use network locations on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT202480)

Comment: Did the college tell you to set up your network configuration manually or did you just do that on your own?  There should be no reason for you to do this.  The college *reserving* you a DHCP lease address (what you describe as "bonding") doesn't force you to manually set up a client.

Comment: @Allan Yes, the college told me to use a particular IP address which is different for different students based on the MAC address of the laptops that they own. This way, they prevent the students from accessing the internet using their other devices and lower the traffic.

Comment: Wow...the network admins at your college don't know what they are doing.  @TimD's answer is the correct one, by the way.

Comment: @Allan Well, I'm curious to know what you want to say. Kindly, explain.

Comment: You can obviously have multiple networks; an open to the public one, one for students and another for staff for example.  All can coexist on the same physical infrastructure using [VLANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN).  You can give out "reserved" addresses for all of these VLANs with a properly configured DHCP server.  Finally, you can secure everything with something like [RADIUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) to authenticate people to the network.  Having folks manually configure IPs is so 1970s because with the free tech that's available, it's literally plug-n-play now

Comment: @Allan Your comment completely went over my head but I think may be you have misunderstood what I'm saying. I mean, I cannot use any other IP address apart from the one given to me.

Comment: No, I understand.  A DHCP lease doesn't have to always change.  I can assign you an IP that never changes and is also sent via DHCP.   It's called "a reserved lease" or a "reserved address" and it's based on your MAC address.  They are having you do manually what is easily done automatically.

Comment: Yeah, You got it. I got your comment but didn't get about  what you said as `plug-n-play` nowadays !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to your phones hotspot you will need to set Configure IPv4 to Use DHCP.

To have different network settings for the same interface you can set up [network locations](https://support.apple.com/HT202480). For instance, add a new location for college with the IPv4 settings you've specified, and when you're using your phones hotspot or somewhere that doesn't require manual setup, use the default Automatic location.

Comment: You gave the answer first, so I accepted yours.

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least) two different network configurations, here one for your college on Wi-Fi with a manual IP address, another one through your phone Wi-Fi with a DHCP attributed IP address.
You can't achieve this with the default `Automatic` "Location" (this is the vocabulary of Apple, because a network configuration is often associated with a physical location, but the term is misleading, in fact we are dealing here with a "network configuration").

You will have to create 2 different "locations":

1. One named `College` or better `College / Wi-Fi` with the manual IP configuration provided by your college,
2. One named `My phone` or better `My phone / Wi-Fi` with the dynamical attribution of your IP address with DHCP.

Once you have created the second network configuration a new menu entry will appear within your  menu: `Location` with a sub-menu which will let you switch from one network configuration to the other.

I even advise to suppress the `Automatic` network configuration (or location if you prefer to stick to the Apple vocabulary) because it is making too many things magically and when one needs to trouble shoot network problems, the magical features are a real nightmare.